# Android - no suitable method found putExtra()

Tags: android

I am trying to write some easy application for android. I have Listview, whitch is filled by data from database (BACKENDLESS). I would like to do this: When I tap on one list item, new page is opened and correct data are displayed.

this is code for onListItemClick:

```
    @Override
protected void onListItemClick( ListView l, View v, int position, long id )
{
    Intent showLocationsIntent = new Intent( this, Detail_page.class ); 
    showLocationsIntent.putExtra("restaurants", totalRestaurants.get( position ) );
    startActivity( showLocationsIntent );
}
```

and this is new activity class:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class  Detail_page extends ListActivity{
private Restaurants restaurant;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_page);

        restaurant = (Restaurants) getIntent().getSerializableExtra( "restaurants" );

        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        new DownloadImage((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView)).execute(restaurant.getPicture());

        String title = restaurant.getName();
    }
}
```

But I have problem with this line `showLocationsIntent.putExtra("restaurants", totalRestaurants.get( position ) );`

Error is: no suitable method found for putExtra(String,Restaurant)

Restaurant is my class

Comment: Please post your Restaurants Class code here. Is it Serialized?

Comment: Restaurants is just an object (assuming), you can't just add an object to an intent bundle. You need to make sure the object is of the proper type (i.e. Parcelable)

Comment: I am trying to reproduce this tutorial [link](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/developing-backendless-android-app-retrieving-data-backend-user-interface-ui/) and there is it like in my post ..

Answer (score 0):

Restaurant  implements Serializable (or Parcelable)

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but is in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing an object. Your Restaurants class should implement Parcelable interface.
[Read this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to add: 
`implements Serializable`
to the object class that is being passed into the intent.

With your code it looks like you are incorrectly using the intent.